# Simple Applescript - Quicktime Issue Play Song

Tags: applescript, quicktime

I'm trying to do a very basic thing using Applescript but I'm having trouble. I am trying to create a very simple Applescript to just open a plain vanilla MP3 file on my desktop with QuickTime Player.

I want to use QuickTime and have it open so user can control it etc.

The basic problem is that the file name or folder path seems to be sometimes randomly causing problems especially when it has spaces in the name or the path folder names etc.

If I double click on any file they all open in QuickTime.

I created a very basic short audio file and saved it with a few different names like:

test1.mp3
test 1.mp3
this is a test.mp3

Then I created this very simple Applescript below.

generally = test1.mp3 will almost always open and start playing, however the other Versions with spaces in the title often produce and error (open thesong line fails i think) like:

The document “test1.mp3” could not be opened.
The file isn’t compatible with QuickTime Player.

error "QuickTime Player got an error: Can’t get document 1. Invalid index." number -1719 from document 1

think this is because it can't open the file.
Any help would be appreciated.

Applescript ...

```
tell application "Finder"
    
    --varied attempts like this...
    set thesong to "drive:Users:me:Desktop:music:test1.mp3" as string
    set thesong to "drive:Users:me:Desktop:music:test1.mp3"
    set thesong to "drive:Users:me:Desktop:music:this is an audio test.mp3" as string
    set thesong to "drive:Users:me:Desktop:test1.mp3" as string

end tell

tell application "QuickTime Player"
    activate
    open thesong
    play document 1
end tell
```

Also I tried adding delays thinking that QuickTime needed time to open before open / play song - but still have random fails...

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
activate
delay 3
open thesong
delay 3
play document 1
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

The Finder is not needed and the delays are not needed either.

Assuming the file is on the desktop create a relative HFS path and add the `alias` keyword after the `open` command

```
set theSong to (path to desktop as text) & "test1.mp3"

tell application "QuickTime Player"
    activate
    set activeDocument to open alias theSong
    play activeDocument
end tell
```

If the file is in the folder `music` on the desktop the path is

```
set theSong to (path to desktop as text) & "music:test1.mp3"
```

Comment: Thanks vadian for your ideas with this

Answer (score 1):

In AppleScript, there are differences between a `string`, a `POSIX file («class furl»)` , and an `alias`.

When you do `set thesong to "drive:Users:me:Desktop:music:test1.mp3" as string` that creates a string, which is just plain text. QuickTime Player's `open` command requires either a `POSIX file` or an `alias`, which is why you get an error message (it doesn't know what to do with a plain text string).

While you ultimately need to end up with a `POSIX file` or `alias`, you can start with a string and then coerce it to the type you want.

Either of the open commands below should work:

```
   set posixFile to "/Users/you/Desktop/file.mp3" as POSIX file
   set aliasFile to ":Users:you:Desktop:file.mp3" as alias

   tell app "QuickTime Player"
       set theDoc to open posixFile
       -- or set theDoc to open aliasFile
       play theDoc
   end tell
```