# Play Quicktime Player video using Applescript

Tags: applescript, quicktime

So I wrote a little script that opens a video I want to play. As soon as it opens, it should play. I tried working with `play`, and even though Quicktime recognizes the word play, it doesn't actually play. What should I do?

```
tell application "Quicktime player"
    open file "/directory/to/the/file/"
    play --doesn't work
end tell
```

Comment: You have to tell the document to play, not the application. Apart from that the spelling of the QuickTime application is wrong and I doubt that it supports POSIX paths.

Comment: @vadian How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66033546/simple-applescript-quicktime-issue-play-song/66033765#66033765

Comment: @vadian, RE: "and I doubt that it supports POSIX paths." --  It supports using a _fully qualified POSIX pathname_ when using, e.g. `open POSIX file "/path/to/filename.mp4"`

Comment: @user3439894 I meant the syntax `file` followed by a POSIX path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a *fully qualified POSIX pathname*, you can use the following, to *open* and *play* the *file*:

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    activate
    set thisFile to open POSIX file "/path/to/filename.mp4"
    play thisFile
end tell
```